# How do you make a button go to a specific page after validating the Username and Password from the Database in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been trying to make a button go to a page when it's done validating that the user put in the right username/password, I've partially done that, the problem is that when I click the button it doesn't validate the username/password, it just goes to the Location. 
I'm using HTML, CSS, javascript and PHP.
This is the code.

```
<?php
// include database and object files
include_once '../config/database.php';
include_once '../objects/user.php';

// get database connection
$database = new Database();
$db = $database->getConnection();

// prepare user object
$user = new User($db);
// set ID property of user to be edited
$user->username = isset($_GET['username']) ? $_GET['username'] : die();
$user->password = base64_encode(isset($_GET['password']) ? $_GET['password'] : die());
// read the details of user to be edited
$stmt = $user->login();
header('Location: ../../../../Home/index.html');
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    // get retrieved row
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    // create array
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => true,
        "message" => "Successfully Login!",
        "id" => $row['id'],
        "username" => $row['username']
    );
}
else{
    $user_arr=array(
        "status" => false,
        "message" => "Invalid Username or Password!",
    );
}
// make it json format
print_r(json_encode($user_arr));
?>
```

Here is a video...
https://youtu.be/Li__rDSdEbs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem is Your locating to the other page before fetching user data,

```
if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
// get retrieved row
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// create array
$user_arr=array(
    "status" => true,
    "message" => "Successfully Login!",
    "id" => $row['id'],
    "username" => $row['username']
);
header('Location: ../../../../Home/index.html');}
```